# What is the logic of C# to create this star pattern?

Tags: c#, nested-for-loop

Hello friends :) I am a noob at programming but enjoying it very much.
can you please help me understand what C# is doing in this code:

```
for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
{
   for(int column = 0; column < row + 1; column++)
      Console.Write("*");
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

In the book it says: the statements of "for" method are:

**Statement 1** is executed once before the execution of the code block.

**Statement 2** defines the condition for executing the code block.

**Statement 3** is executed (every time) after the code block has been executed.

---

**PROBLEM:**
I understand well this code below, and why it prints what it prints:

```
for(int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
{
   for(int column = 0; column < 10; column++)
      Console.Write("*");
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

**QUESTION:** So why the first code prints a different pattern? since the second statement of the inner "for" loop just checks a condition to be true or false.

Isn't the second statement of the "for" loop just to know when to stop or continue the iteration?

Thanks for your time
regards

JP

Comment: Your two blocks of code appear to be identical, except for `col` being renamed as `column` - I think you didn't paste exactly what you intended to.

Comment: You are right, I pasted the same code twice. now look at it please

Comment: If you understand what `column < 10` is doing, then `column < row + 1` is exactly the same - it's just a different value being used on each row, rather than a constant 10.

Comment: Thanks for replying :), the book said, that column < 10 is a condition that returns true until it’s met and then it returns false and stops iterating… I thought it was exactly the same as the other but just a different value por the counter… but if you run the two codes, the results are very different… and then I got confused

Comment: You can run this code under debugger - best way to understand step by step what it does. Otherwise, this question is out of scope for SO

Comment: Ask yourself: for both cases, what number of columns are printed for row 0 and for row 1?

Answer (score 1):

The `for` statement is occasionally confusing when you're starting out. The 3 expressions given to it are initializer, exit condition and increment. The exit condition on your inner loop in this case is the important part: `column < row + 1`. Since the `row` value is constantly changing the inner loop will run different numbers of iterations.

You can (mostly, ignoring a couple of things to do with variable scope) rewrite any `for` loop as a `while` loop. Your code can be expanded to:

```
// Outer initializer
int row = 0;

// Outer loop and exit condition
while (row < 10)
{
    // Inner loop initializer
    int column = 0;
    
    // Inner loop and exit condition
    while (column < row + 1)
    {
        // Inner loop body
        Console.Write("*");

        // Inner loop increment
        column++;
    }

    // Remainder of outer loop body
    Console.WriteLine();

    // Outer loop increment
    row++;
}
```

That's roughly equivalent, and hopefully it's a little easier to trace through. `row` starts at 0, meaning the inner loop will run once printing a single star. Then `row` increments to 1, producing 2 stars... and so on.

As Felix commented, stepping through the code in a debugger will show you what is happening. The insights you gain from seeing the real state of the program as it is running are valuable aids in learning how the various elements of the program function. And always remember that almost everything can be done in multiple ways.